# Why is there no option to initialize parts of UserForms? Also, why does the workaround not work?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create as UserForm in VBA in Word and first up, I'm trying to populate a ListBox with options using the Initialize function, but when I look at the list of functions I can use for the ListBox, Initialize isn't there. I try creating a function "ListBox1_Initialize" to do the same thing, but that does nothing for the UserForm. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Initialize()
    ListBox1.AddItem ("option 1")
    ListBox1.AddItem ("option 2")
    ListBox1.AddItem ("option 3")
End Sub
```

Comment: There's a `UserForm_Initialize` event you can use to initialize your controls.  Your workaround doesn't work because you can't invent event handlers for events which are not provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fill the ListBox options only once, you can use the Document_Open event.

[image: Word Document_Open]